# How to prevent users from deleting a directory?

Tags: permissions, files

I tried "chattr +i DIRNAME", it's great, but I cannot create files in the DIR after chattr. What else are there to prevent users from deleting a Directory?

```
root@HOST ~] mkdir test
[root@HOST ~] chattr +i test
[root@HOST ~] cd test
[root@HOST ~/test] touch sth
touch: cannot touch `sth': Permission denied
[root@HOST ~/test] cd ..
[root@HOST ~] chattr -i test
[root@HOST ~] cd test
[root@HOST ~/test] touch sth
[root@HOST ~/test]
```

UPDATE: only the directory deletion is important, so I still need the files to be deleted in it

Comment: Take a look at `/tmp` and `/var/tmp`. While every user can create files there, he/she can delete only his own files/directories, but not the directory itselv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what is wrong with a simple chown/chmod?:

```
cd /tmp
mkdir question
sudo chown root:root question
[sudo] password for user: 
chmod 777 ./question
touch sth
rm sth
cd ..
rm question -rf
rm: cannot remove `question': Operation not permitted
```

OK, let me tell you what is wrong with this: every user has all access to every file in the `question` directory due to the `777` permissions. It is better to

- create a new group `groupadd question`
- `mkdir question`
- `chown root:question ./question`
- `chmod 770 ./question`
- add the users that must have access to the files to the new group: `usermod -G group user`

The important trick here is that the directory has a different owner than any of the users that will try to delete it.

Comment: It depends also where this directory is located. If somebody from question group has rwx rights on the directory containing question directory it will be able to delete it.

Comment: Add an extra `sudo chmod o+t ..` to set the `t` flag on the parent directory. The `t` flag will disallow to remove a file that is not owned by the user. `t` is commonly used on `/tmp` to do exactly that. UserA cannot delete files owned by UserB.

Comment: Or once again just put the correct ownership an permission bits on the directory.

Comment: It doesn't work in docker containers. :(

Comment: Hey @jippie I'm trying to setup a SMB share and I have a backup directory with the following permissions: `drwxr-x--T  1 admin users` and the folder inside it is: `drwxrwx---  1 admin Elias`. I've tried for so long but no matter what I do I can still delete the sub-directory. I **must** be doing something completely wrong. (I don't really care how I do it but I want a directory for every user, that only they can access, but the users are not allowed to delete the directory itself).

Answer (score 16):

Create a file ".protected" and do as root

```
chattr +i .protected
```

You can then delete all files except `.protected` within this directory,
thus the directory can't be deleted by any other user.

Comment: Simple, and effective. Great answer.

Comment: It doesn't work in docker containers. :(

Comment: To delete it, use "chattr -i [filename]" to remove the immutable attribute.

Comment: However, a user will **still be able to move the directory** to a completely other place up or down in the directory tree. For all intents or purposes, the end result may be equally dire.

Comment: Here is [how to prevent the directory from moving](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/594167/39845).

Comment: This will make directory **immutable**. Means, nobody, not even root will be able to put any files inside, change permissions ,etc.

Answer (score 4):

```
chattr +a
```

should do the job. You can create files inside but you won't be able to delete them.

Comment: i updated the question