# Linux File Permission Query

Tags: permissions

I want to set a permission for a file `abcd.php` in such a way so that it can be executed/run by the user/program but the file cannot be deleted or downloaded by user using SFTP or FTP.

I tried a lot to search but couldn't get a perfect answer for it.

Comment: Related - [Prevent a user from deleting the folders and files in his own home](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/189871/100397)

Answer (score 1):

(Note: this sounds a bit like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You might want to describe the actual problem that makes you want to set such permissions to `abcd.php` instead.)

Let's look at what your requirements mean:

- *file can be executed/run by the user*: for a PHP file, that means the file must be **readable** for the program running as the user, possibly with the **execute** bit added. This is pretty normal and can be done easily.
- *cannot be deleted by user*: this means the file must be located **in a directory that is not writeable by the user, and has no parent directories that would be writeable by the user either**. This essentially means the file must be in a location that is fully read-only for the user. (If the user is not allowed to delete the file, you'll probably not want to allow the user to modify the file's contents either.)
- *file cannot be downloaded by user*: unfortunately, this is in conflict with your first requirement. When Linux file permissions specify the file as readable, the file will be **readable for any purpose**: there is no way to use file permissions to designate the file as "readable for execution but not for downloading". You would have to use some other means to enforce this kind of restriction.

Since `*.php` files are often used with web pages, problems like this are often solvable by running the webserver as a separate user account with SFTP/FTP access completely disabled, and *configuring the web server* to only output the results of executing the PHP file, never the actual PHP file itself.

If a local user needs to execute the PHP file, they can then run a command like `curl http://localhost/some/path/abcd.php` and have the web server process execute the file for them, while the user themselves won't need to have any direct access to the `abcd.php` file at the filesystem level at all.

If you are using PHP as a tool for local scripting, you might not want to involve a web server, and instead use `sudo`, [as described in FelixJN's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/669113/258991).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `PHP` is a scripting language after all. I.e. for executing one must be able to read it.

You may however circumvent this by changing the owner and allow a passwordless sudo for execution. E.g.

```
 $ls -a file.php
 -r-x------ 1 phpuser phpuser 15 15. Sep 13:12 file.php
```

with phpuser not being `john`, the user you worry about. Then have an entry like

```
 $cat /etc/sudoers
 %phpreaders ALL=(phpuser) NOPASSWD: /path/to/file.php
```

and add your desired users in the `phpreaders`-group. With the above `sudoers` entry, members of the `phpreaders` group may execute the script on `ALL` servers without password, but it will be run as `phpuser`. So execution will be done by `john` calling

```
sudo -u phpuser /path/to/file.php
```

Be aware, that it is not run as `john` but as `phpuser`.

Comment: Actually, user `john` would have to use `sudo -u phpuser /path/to/file.php`. Without the `-u phpuser`, sudo would attempt to run the file as `root`, which would fail since `john` would not be authorized to run that command as `root`, but only as `phpuser`.