# Stop user from deleting file in directory

Tags: files, permissions, rhel

This is the scenario

1. There is one directory /test which is owned by oracle.dba
2. I created new user TEST who will have permission to create NEW files but it should not be able to delete the files he/she created

I tried multiple ways even acls but not working.

Comment: You're right.  If you want the users to be able to create new files then they will always be able to delete them if the permissions or ownership don't change.

Comment: Yes, it allows to change the content of file but even owner cant delete the file.

Comment: Linux is limited in this area. I am working to extend that.

Comment: Duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55259/how-to-prevent-users-from-deleting-a-directory ?

Comment: No it's not. OP wants to partition classic "write" into more specific actions, like "create" but not "remove".

Comment: not really doable...removing and creating a file depends on the permissions of the parent folder, and if a user can create a file he will be able to remove it as well, even if he has 0 permissions on it (when using `umask 777`)

Comment: The closest way I could see this kind of situation being handled is to make a command to create the new files.  If you change your question to allow that as an answer, I'll answer it.

Comment: @OmiPenguin:  Since it is completely impossible to do exactly what you're asking, you should open your question to alternate solutions.

Comment: Please expand on your scenario. It's strange that it's ok for the test user to truncate their files to length 0 but not to remove them. [There's probably a different way to do whatever you want to do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no way of doing this using just standard UNIX privileges. The problem here is that (as far as I know) a newly created file is always owned by its creator — and if you are able to create the file, you have write privileges to the parent directory, and can therefore delete the file as well.

You can use the sticky bit to prevent users from deleting *other users* files, and you can use the SETGID bit on the directory to change the group of newly created files, but on Linux, the SETUID directory bit is ignored.

You could create a daemon that monitors the directory (perhaps using some kind of file alteration monitor) and changes ownership to oracle.dba after the file is created. There is a race condition, though – an attacker can delete the file before the daemon notices it's there.

And even if you succeed, be aware that as long as you have write permissions, you can truncate the file to zero length, thus destroying the contents without having to explicitly delete the file.

Comment: Yes, thats the problem SUID is not working on new files. sticky bit only works with SGID. At this moment my weak mind tells me to use "chattr +i" .

Comment: @OmiPenguin I don't see how chattr will help you. If you are willing to change permissions on files *after* they are created, you can just go for the chmod I've proposed. `chattr +i` will prevent you from modifying the file at all, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: "chattr +i" will allow me to modify the files, but will not permit to delete any file not even root user will be able to delete them, So to delete a file i have to set chattr to none to delete file , then after deleting files i reset chatter to "chattr +i"

Comment: Why do you answer a question that you agree can't be answered?  OP needs to learn how permissions and ownership works.  I actually have a much better solution to allow file creation without giving ownership but it wouldn't answer the question either which is why I don't post it.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I feel that “this can't be done under these circumstances” is a valuable answer. If you have a better solution, why don't you post it? I'd like to know how to do this without resorting to ugly hacks.

Comment: @OmiPenguin I see, you'll `chattr +i` the directory, not the files. That will, unfortunately, also prevent creating the files – you'll therefore need a special command (or whatever) to unchattr the dir, copy the files there and chattr it again. And as soon as you start doing that, you can as well do without the chattr and use a foreign-owned directory (unwritable by users) plus a service to copy the files on demand. Then you'll have to remember to use the special service instead of standard `cp`, `mv` etc.