# Stop folders or directories from being moved

Tags: filesystems

We create a directory or folder for each client record in our database so documents can be saved into that folder for accessing by via the client record, in other words a document management system.

The problem is that users are always accidentally dragging and dropping the folders somewhere else.

I cannot block write access as the users should continue to be able to create files within that folder. I just need to stop the folder from being moved.

Answer (score 1):

- If you set the [Sticky bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) on a folder any user can create files, but
  only the owner of a file can delete/rename/move it.
- SELinux
- Put the folders on a server so they can only be copied or added to
  not moved. Assuming one client computer per folder. Users can't move
  the root of a smb share.
- Use a web interface (or WebDav) to manage the clients
  interaction with the files/folders.

Answer (score 0):

Place a [sticky bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit#Usage) on the parent directory, to render it append only:

```
$ sudo chmod +t parent_directory/
```

Now, proceed with changing the ownership of the child directory to `root`. This renders the child directory unmovable. Group ownership is irrelevant.

```
$ sudo chown root: parent_directory/child_directory
```

Note, however, that this does not protect `child_directory` from being deleted by users who do not own the `child_directory`.

Comment: My understanding is that this does prevent it from being deleted.  Can you clarify on that comment?