# Prevent deleting files in particular directory

Tags: permissions, password, root, chmod, chown

Recently, I deleted some files accidentally. Fortunately, I was able to recover them. That is why I would like to prevent deleting files in a particular directory but still allow to create new files and modify them. So, permissions should be rwx, but if I want to delete **ANY** file (created by **ANY** user) in this directory, I should be prompted to input a password. Is this possible somehow on Debian Testing?

Comment: similar question on AU [How can I set up a password for the 'rm' command?](https://askubuntu.com/q/865023/283843), by the way you want password protect `find -delete` or `mv * afile` or any other scripting way?

Comment: I am just reading the thread you mentioned. I want to protect just the normal `rm afile` which I can do through the file manager. It does not have to be secure, but just prevent me from making mistakes.

Comment: This seems to be what I want: https://askubuntu.com/a/866003/692458 Is it possible to change the rm executable only in a specific directory and not everywhere?

Comment: see also [How to prevent users from deleting a directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55259/how-to-prevent-users-from-deleting-a-directory).

Comment: Maybe directory protection would suffice for me. `chattr +a directory` also looks not bad. Is there something similar which allows me to rename and change the files?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `aufs` / `unionfs`. You put the files which are to be protected in the read-only level.

Real file deletion could be realized with password protection by having the read-only directory in

```
/path/to/ro
```

with `ro` belonging to a special user and having 755 permissions. Deletions could be done with `sudo` then:

```
sudo -u rmuser rm /path/to/ro/file
```